# TUI system monitor that's functionally similar to this Gnome widget?

Tags: software-recommendation, system-monitor, tui

I really like this system monitor widget for Gnome.

[image]

It shows the recent *history* of CPU, RAM, network, disk and GPU usage (not just current status). Is there a similar [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) program?

---

I found `s-tui`, but it looks pretty broken (doesn't save settings) and limited (only CPU frequency and utilization are working).

Comment: What is TUI? From which package you installed it?

Comment: @N0rbert Text-based UI. I added a link.